# Alter scope data in a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm developing an app with angular and I want to do some math on an object variable in an edit page.

For instance when I get my proposition (the object), I want to set `proposition.marge_theorique` like this `proposition.marge_theorique= 2 * proposition.marge_grille` at page load.

First thing I do is that I get the object with the API, and then I call my function `calcul()` that has to do the math.

My problem is that I don't know how to tell calcul to alter the $scope.proposition.

Here is my code

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('propositionCtrl',['$scope', 'propositionRepository', '$http',
    function ($scope, propositionRepository, $http) {
       // $scope.proposition = { marge_propose: 3 };



        //////////////////////////////DEFINITIONS////////////////////////////////////
        $scope.submit = function () {
            $http.put('/api/propositionapi', $scope.proposition);
        }




        function getProposition() {
            propositionRepository.getProposition(function (result) {
                $scope.proposition = result;

            }
            )
        }

        function calcul(contexte) {
           contexte.proposition.marge_theorique = contexte.proposition.marge_grille * 2;
        }

        ///////////////////////////////UTILISATION///////////////////////////////////
        console.log("on est dans la page");
        getProposition();
        calcul($scope);
;
    }])

app.factory('propositionRepository', function ($http) {
    return {
        getProposition: function (callback) {
            $http.get('/api/propositionapi/3').success(callback);
        }
    }
})
```

I've also tried to do it this way

```
        function calcul() {
           $scope.proposition.marge_theorique = $scope.proposition.marge_grille * 2;
        }
```

and then just call `calcul()` but it does not work either...

What should I do?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getProposition` call is async in nature, you need to wait for the response to be available. You can use the callback. Update the `getProposition` function.

```
function getProposition() {
            propositionRepository.getProposition(function (result) {
                $scope.proposition = result;
                calcul($scope);
            })
        }
```

And remove the call `calcul($scope);` done after `getProposition();` from the end of controller

Comment: Thanks it works!

Thing is, when the user changes the value of proposition.marge_grille in the edit page, calcul has to be called. 

I don't know how to do it...

Comment: I don't know about the structure of you app, but look at angular watches. They can track model changes and trigger event handlers.